# Number of features in SVM Kernel matrix

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, kernel-trick

I'm trying to implement the SVM algorithm manually, and I've succeeded in doing so with the case of a linear kernel (no kernel function).

Now I'd like to add a gaussian kernel to the algorithm, but I'm facing a size mismatch problem. The way I understand it, is that by applying your original examples to the kernel you create a new feature matrix. If I have m training examples then the new kernel matrix would become an (m×m) matrix regardless of how many features I had, and the weights vector would be of length (m+1).

Then when I apply a test set to algorithm with k examples and each example having n features, I get a dimension mismatch error: n != m+1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel matrix is $m\times m$ if you have $m$ training examples because it's the dot product matrix in the transformed space. But, weight vector has nothing to do with $m$ and its dimension is the *original* feature dimension (+1 if you embed the bias term inside the weights) when the kernel is linear. When it's not, you don't calculate the weights since you may not know the explicit transformation. The kernel is directly used in the task, e.g. an [explicit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/434252/how-to-classify-new-data-point-for-kernel-svm) formulation for binary classification.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still confused. How can I make the algorithm learn n (+1) weights from the new (m×m) feature matrix?

Comment: Hi @Red-Sky, I've included more comments.

Comment: The link makes it clearer. I suppose the alpha terms would be the weights learned from the training examples. Thanks.

Comment: alpha are the support vector coefs